# TLS handshake fails with OpenSSL 3.0 but succeeds with OpenSSL 1.1.0

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I'm migrating some code from OpenSSL 1.1.0 to OpenSSL 3.0.
According to the [OpenSSLWiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Upgrading_to_OpenSSL_3.0_from_OpenSSL_1.1.1), upgrading to OpenSSL 3.0 from OpenSSL 1.1.1 should be relatively straight forward in most cases.
The code I have compiles fine and links with OpenSSL 3.0, so no problems there. It also runs without problems until the moment `SSL_connect` is called. The TLS handschake fails with *'verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate'*. However with OpenSSL 1.1.0 the TLS handshake succeeds, without changing anything.

I have a certificate chain setup by following the [OpenSSL Certificate Authority](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html) tutorial.
So the chain consist of 3 certificates:

1. Root CA (SS)
2. Intermediate CA (RCA)
3. Server (ICA)

The Root and Intermediate certificates are merged in 1 chain file called `ca-chain.cert.pem`.
The code making the TLS connection is straight forward, based upon the following, simplified, code snippet:

```cpp
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "ca-chain.cert.pem", NULL);
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock_fd);
SSL_connect(ssl); // Handshake fails in OpenSSL 3.0
```

For testing I use the `s_server` command:

```sh
openssl s_server -key server.key.pem -cert server.cert.pem -accept 5301
```

This works fine with OpenSSL 1.1.0. Even with the `verify` command (OpenSSL 3.0) this looks to be ok:

```sh
openssl verify -CAfile ca-chain.cert.pem server.cert.pem 
server.cert.pem: OK
```

The issue seems to be that the certificate of the Intermediate CA is not present in the trust store (e.g. is a trusted certificate) with OpenSSL 3.0, while it is considered trusted with OpenSSL 1.1.0.
I got it working when I added the `-cert_chain ca.cert.pem` option to the `s_server` command, which will also send the Intermediate CA certificate to the client. In that case I also don't need the `ca-chain.cert.pem` file, and can just load the `root.cert.pem` file.
However I would like to keep the same behavior as before (with OpenSSL 1.1.0). Is there anyone who knows how to achieve this with OpenSSL 3.0? Is there a (new) option that I missed that needs to be set for this?
I would also like to know why the Intermediate CA certificate is no longer considered trusted with OpenSSL 3.0, while it still is with OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem you are reporting. Please provide a fully reproducible example with full (but minimal) code and test certificates.